# Split single line with multiple words into many lines with x words on each

Tags: bash, sed, split, xargs

I have a big text file, which contains only 1 line. It looks like this:

```
blaalibababla.ru text text text text what's the weather like tooday? blaazzabla.zu some_text blabewdwefla.au it is important not to be afraid of sed blabkrlqbla.ru wjenfkn lkwnef lkwnefl blarthrthbla.net 1234 e12edq 42wsdfg blablabla.com this should finally end
```

I need a way to make it look like this:

```
blaalibababla.ru text text text text what's the weather like tooday?
blaazzabla.zu some_text
blabewdwefla.au it is important not to be afraid of sed
blabkrlqbla.ru wjenfkn lkwnef lkwnefl
blarthrthbla.net 1234 e12edq 42wsdfg 
blablabla.com this should finally end
```

I know how to do it with single domain name and `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/blablabla.ru/\n&/g' file.txt
```

"But not with the additional text afterwards." - It is not what I mean.

If `sed` is not the best way, please let me know.

UPD:
Here is my text file:

```
wsd.qwd.qwd.kjqnwk.ru PUPPETD CRITICAL 2017-01-13 00:09:52   lor notify-by-sms FILE_AGE CRITICAL:   /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml is 2438046 seconds old and 19459 bytes   zm-goas-04.asdg.net LOAD CRITICAL 2017-01-13 00:10:32   tech-lor notify-by-telegram CRITICAL - load average: 42.91,   49.91, 53.88   glas07.kvm.ext.asdg.ru PUPPETD CRITICAL 2017-01-13 00:28:02   lor notify-by-sms FILE_AGE CRITICAL:   /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml is 19821 seconds old and 26337 bytes
```

I need it to look like:

```
wsd.qwd.qwd.kjqnwk.ru PUPPETD CRITICAL 2017-01-13 00:09:52   lor notify-by-sms FILE_AGE CRITICAL:   /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml is 2438046 seconds old and 19459 bytes   
zm-goas-04.asdg.net LOAD CRITICAL 2017-01-13 00:10:32   tech-lor notify-by-telegram CRITICAL - load average: 42.91,   49.91, 53.88   
glas07.kvm.ext.asdg.ru PUPPETD CRITICAL 2017-01-13 00:28:02   lor notify-by-sms FILE_AGE CRITICAL:   /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml is 19821 seconds old and 26337 bytes
```

Comment: Can you give some actual data as an example? I'm curious what `some_text` really looks like.

Comment: edit with your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to split on this pattern: `([-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+){1,}` for domain names.

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/ +(([-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]){1,}) */\n\1/g' file
```

Note that any string matching one space followed by `[-a-z0-9]`, followed by a `.` and by `[a-z]` characters will be processed as a domain name.

Comment: sed -r 's/ +(([-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]){1,} ) */\n\1/g' file - doesn't work
sed -r 's/ +(([-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]){1,}) */\n\1/g' file - works great
Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Glad to help. Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Could you please change in your answer from this line:
    sed -r 's/ +(([-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]){1,} ) */\n\1/g' file
to this:
   sed -r 's/ +(([-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]){1,}) */\n\1/g' file
?

Answer (score 5):

An ever simpler way using `xargs` to process `n` records at a time, which in your case is just `2`

```
xargs -n2 <file
blablabla.ru some_text
blablabla.zu some_text
blablabla.au some_text
blablabla.ru some_text
blablabla.net some_text
blablabla.com some_text
```

where the `-n` flag according to the `man xargs` page is,

```
-n max-args, --max-args=max-args
      Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments 
      will be used if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded, unless the
      -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.
```

To replace back the original file, do

```
xargs -n2 <file >tmpfile; mv tmpfile file
```

Comment: @JamesBrown: Yup :), the last 4k went in a  jiffy

Comment: Great answer @Inian!  I was working on something and I just needed this `xargs -n`.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted you and looks like that sent you over the top!  Congratulations.

Comment: Now, its 100k next. :D

Comment: I was always thinkin that after 1k I chill out. Then it was 5k and now you got 10k and I can't quit before that!

Comment: @JamesBrown: Thats exactly what I had for `bash`, gold. Hit it and then actually get a life :D

Answer (score 2):

Awk:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/([^ ]+ ){2}/,"&\n")' file
blablabla.ru some_text 
blablabla.zu some_text 
blablabla.au some_text 
blablabla.ru some_text 
blablabla.net some_text 
blablabla.com some_text
```

Explained:

Replaces every twice repeating `[^ ]+` (string of nonspaces and a space) with itself (`&`) and a newline `\n`. If there is a leftover (ie. a non-match) in the end, it won't get printed (unless you wrap the `gsub(...)` with `{}1`).